# How can I register an event spy with a Maven job that is run by a Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I want to profile Maven builds. Maven's event spies make profiling possible (spies listen to events). Usually the user puts the jar file containing an event spy in the folder maven-3.x.x/lib/ext or uses -Dmaven.ext.class.path on the command line to add the jar to the container classpath.

Both approaches work with the Maven command line but not with Jenkins because Jenkins seems to bypass some maven command line logic. Therefore, my question:

How can I register an EventSpy with a Maven job that is run by a Jenkins?

Comment: The problem here is that Jenkins itself has an event spy already running to identify some situations which is needed in jenkins. If you like having your own eventspy you need to prevent using Maven plugin in Jenkins.